# Why does my Visual Studio Webforms application not see into the connected SQL Server schema?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019

A Visual Studio 2019 Webforms (VB) application, which connects to a local SQL Server demo database (`AdventureWorks2019`), has a GridView control which CAN connect to a SQL source, and displays a list of tables in the database, but if I use the Configure date source wizard to build the query, it shows an error which states that the query failed. I think it's a factor of the 'user' access to the schemas in the database, but I cannot see where to specify the schema in Visual Studio.

Why can VS 'see' the tables in the wizard, but not at the query stage?

Details:

- ASP.NET (VB) Web Application using .NET Framework 4.7.2
- Using Webforms template with HTTPS not configured
- Modifying the `Default.aspx` file

Connection string is:

```
Data Source=LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2019;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxxxxx
```

Adding a GridView control and using the Configure Data Source option. The default table selection provides a list of tables in the database, but does not carry schema information. If I use the Custom SQL statement option, the Query Builder DOES include schema. However, if I use this option, the Advanced options to generate Update, Delete, and Insert queries is not available.

Why does the default option in VS not carry/recognize schema?

Tried creating a user with specific schema permissions in the database. Tried to find settings in VS to specify the schema.

Comment: Try creating an <asp:ObjectDataSource object yourself that the GridView can use.